# Does Parent obj = new Child(); make sense?

Tags: java, inheritance

In Java:

```
Parent obj = new Child();
```

I created an object of type Parent. I assume that I can only invoke the methods defined in Parent class. Thus, I can't invoke the "additional" methods defined in Child or access variables defined in Child.
So I think it's a waste of memory since I have newed a instance of Child which takes additional memory space than Parent. To this point I think it does not make sense.
Can anyone please give some reason/example where this make sense?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it does make sense.

You would do this if you want to use a Child, but constrain your interaction with it to `Parent` methods.

This idiom is particularly common with Java collections:

```
List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Comment: Most often used when the Parent class is abstract, or when the Parent class is a part of the public interface for a library and the Child class is an implementation detail.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is part of the polymorphism and inheritance programming concepts.

Answer (score 1):

this idiom is used to favor change of concrete implementation. According to Joshua Bloch in Effective Java (Item 52)

> If you get into the habit of using interfaces as types, your program will be much more flexible.If you decide that you want to switch implementations , all you have to do is change the class name in the constructor (or use a different static factory)