# What is the difference between "Parent c = new Child()" and "Child c = new Child()"?

Tags: java, inheritance, constructor

I am new to Java so please bear with me, I tried looking this question up but I'm having trouble since I don't know the underlying terms involved in this question.

Assuming:

```
class Parent {}

class Child extends Parent {}
```

What is the difference between:

```
Parent c = new Child();
```

and

```
Child c = new Child();
```

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

Comment: One difference: give `Child` a method that isn't in `Parent` and try to call it with both ways.

Comment: (The difference is the type of the variable..)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4447924/what-does-base-b2-new-child-signify?rq=1 , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4454439/what-is-the-advantage-to-declaring-an-object-of-one-type-as-in-instance-of-anoth?lq=1 ,  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9163950/does-parent-obj-new-child-make-sense

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At runtime there is no difference.

There is a difference only for the Java compiler (and type checker). In the first case you are declaring that the most informative thing that you know about the `c` is that it is a `Parent`, even if the runtime type is more specific.

This has two main effects:

- `c` can be used when a `Parent` is needed but not when a `Child` is needed
- if you want to change the type of `c` to another type (let's suppose `class Nephew extends Parent`) the only necessary thing is to change the instantiation (eg. `new Child()` becomes `new Nephew()`

The second effect is a consequence of the fact that, if the code compiles and `c` is declared as a `Parent`, this implies that you are not using any feature which is not already declared in `Parent`, so every other class which extends from `Parent` is a valid [substitute](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).

Answer (score 0):

remember this in java- a parent class object can hold the reference to a child class object..

this is exactly what is being done here.

plus look at this
[Does Parent obj = new Child(); make sense?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9163950/does-parent-obj-new-child-make-sense)